# Android - Specify theme of each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I try to write an application using one activity-multiple fragment approach. Some pages should has translucent toolbar but not others.

```
new MyFragment(isTranslucentToolbar)
```

But theme property belongs to application.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

If I set this property as below, I cannot change theme of the fragment.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

If I set the theme as transparent, how do I create a fragment with non-translucent toolbar? I can arrange the margin&padding values of fragment root layout and statusbar bar color programmatically.

Is this any way of this task?

Answer (score 3):

Keep the normal theme with the ActionBar enabled.

When you want to hide/show the ActionBar:

```
activity.getSupportActionBar().hide(); //for AppCompatActivity
activity.getActionBar().hide(); //for Activity

activity.getSupportActionBar.show(); //for AppCompatActivity
activity.getActionBar().show(); //for Activity
```

When you want to change the translucency of the status bar:

```
activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Comment: @us2956 can you maybe post a picture of what you want?

Answer (score 3):

In your fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme_Transparent, true); 
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Your_fragment_layout, container, false);
   return view;
}
```

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท it doesn't affect status bar

Comment: I would just define an appbar in each fragment and use theme without action bar `.NoActionBar`. Then the context wrapper will also affect the appbar. Sure, it adds some extra code, but it keeps the theme from fragment separated from the theme of activity.

Answer (score 0):

try `setTheme()` method in your java file

**EDIT 1:**

Setting Theme in manifest is usually used for Activity.

If you want to set Theme for Fragment, add next code in the onCreateView() of the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourCustomTheme);

    // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

    // inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
    return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
}
```

Also give a try to this code segment if above doesn't work

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: `Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Fragment toolbar");
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.MyTranparentTheme, true);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.translucentColor)));
` setTheme  or applyTheme don't work for transparent status bar.

Comment: @us2956  I've made an edit in the answer. Check if the code works